# Drawing a directed line based on dataframe indexes?

Tags: postgis, carto, sql, geopandas, cartoframes

I trying to draw a directed graph based on a geopandas dataframe with the Cartoframe library.

The Geopandas dataframe has the following structure:

```
  deviceId  routeLoad  longitude   latitude                  geometry
0    depot          0   20.618602  30.959910  POINT (20.61860 30.9599)
1   pointA          8   20.057890  39.516000  POINT (20.05789 30.4160)
2   pointB         11   20.047890  39.516000  POINT (20.05789 30.5160)
3   pointC         14   20.043920  39.335000  POINT (20.04392 30.3350)
```

Right now, I have the possibility to display these points on the map with `Map(Layer(test))` but I do not have any idea how to create directed graph with CartoFrame and if it possible to do it without too much work.

The ultimate objective is to have a path going through the different observations depicted inside the geopandas dataframe.

For instance:

```
depot --> pointA --> pointB --> pointC --> depot
```

[image]

For simplicity, this is the sample code.

```
import pandas as pd
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, points_from_xy
from cartoframes.viz import Layer, Map, color_category_style, popup_element
test = pd.DataFrame([{'deviceId': 'depot', 'routeLoad': 0, 'longitude': 20.618602, 'latitude': 30.959910},
                    {'deviceId': 'pointA', 'routeLoad': 8, 'longitude': 20.057890, 'latitude': 39.416000},
                    {'deviceId': 'pointB', 'routeLoad': 11, 'longitude': 20.047890, 'latitude': 39.516000},
                    {'deviceId': 'pointC', 'routeLoad': 14, 'longitude': 20.043920, 'latitude': 39.335000}])
test = GeoDataFrame(test, geometry=points_from_xy(test.longitude, test.latitude))
Map(Layer(test, popup_hover=[
        popup_element('deviceId'),
        popup_element('routeLoad')

    ]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two alternatives. On the one hand, you can create/read a table from a PostGIS query [using `ST_Makeline`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html) using something like:

```
SELECT      ST_MakeLine(the_geom_webmercator ORDER BY track_seg_id ASC) AS the_geom_webmercator,
            track_fid,
            row_number() OVER() AS cartodb_id 
FROM        table_name 
GROUP BY    track_fid
```

On the other, you can use a similar approach as this answer with `groupby` and geopandas:

```
    lines = points.groupby(['track_fid'])['geometry'].apply(
      lambda x: LineString(x.tolist())
    )
```

In both cases, you would need to replicate the first row in order "to close the circle". Also, you would need to have a track_seg_id to order the steps of the segment and if you have more than one line, something like a track_fid for grouping each of the lines.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed, it is working but I am wondering if we can exploit that more easily. Others visualization tools like `kepler.gl` allows you to draw edges if you have the source and target points instantaneously. Moreover, if your dataframe is sorted and you only have the source point, you can directly compute the target points with `shift()` function.

Comment: I dont work for CARTO. Maybe you could send a feature request in one of their repos. But please, if you think my answer is correct, mark it as solved.